# Xamarin error - "Connection to the layout renderer failed"

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.android, xamarin-studio

Todas as vezes que tento abrir o arquivo Main.axml aparece esse erro : [image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Não sei como resolver, alguém pode da uma ajudinha ?